# Spring JDO - makePersistent not returning created object

Tags: spring, jdo

I'm using Spring and JDO connecting to a MySQL database. 
When I persist an object, I am expecting to see the created object returned by the `makePersistent()` method. It does return an object, but this object only has the ID of the newly created object. All the other fields that were persisted now have a value of null.

In the code example below, I insert a value of 12 with the `carouselNumber`. The returned object has that value set to NULL and the id has the newly created ID value from the database.

I've used `JDOHelper.getObjectState()` and found that my object is in a Transient state.

I'm wondering if there is some annotation that I am missing to tell `JDO` to return all the values on the object, rather than just the newly generated ID.

**EDIT:**
I've done some further exploring and found that when I use the raw Datanucleus JDP API that thsi works fine. The problem only seems to be when I use Spring's JDO template. I'd really like to get an understanding of why this differs. Thanks

Thanks in Advance,

Brian.

```
@PersistenceCapable(table = "CAROUSEL", identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)

public class Carousel {

    @PrimaryKey(column = "ID")
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.INCREMENT)
    private Long id;

   @Column(name = "CAROUSEL_NUM")
    private int carourselNumber;
```

......

```
public class CarouselDAOImpl extends JdoDaoSupport implements ICarouselDAO {

  public Carousel insert(Carousel carousel) {
    return getJdoTemplate().makePersistent(carousel);
   }
```

.....

Answer (score 0):

The makePersistent method alters the carousel object you've passed in to generate an ID, so it doesn't need to return anything.  Just make your method void and use the carousel you've passed in.

Comment: Hi Dave. Yeah I realize that. I've tried what you suggested and the problem is the same. The difference I can see with using Springs JDOTemplate is that it makes the object transient, whereas using the JDO API directly the object comes back as hollow. This means that when I call getCarouselNumber it lazily loads the value.